# Non-DER format ECDSA with EVP_DigestSign() in OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, ecdsa

I want to use EVP_DigestSign() for ECDSA signing because it works for OpenSSL 1.1.1 and OpenSSL 3.x and it can be used for RSA and other.

I have it working, but the output I get is the DER-encoded ECDSA signature. I just want the r and s values without the DER wrapping. (I am implementing COSE, RFC 9052, and it doesn't use DER).

I can get this with ECDSA_do_sign() but this function is to be deprecated.

How to I control the output format of EVP_DigestSign()?

Answer (score 2):

Sign as normal using `EVP_DigestSign()`. Take the signature that is emitted and pass it to the `d2i_ECDSA_SIG` function to create an `ECDSA_SIG` object (note that this is *not* deprecated in 3.0). Then you can use `ECDSA_SIG_get0_r()` and `ECDSA_SIG_get0_s()` to extract the `r` and `s` values from it.

`d2i_ECDSA_SIG` is documented on this page:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/d2i_ECDSA_SIG.html

`ECDSA_SIG_get0_r()` and `ECDSA_SIG_get0_s()` are documented on this page:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/ECDSA_SIG_get0_r.html

Comment: Thanks for this. It works. Appreciate the help!

But note that this does require and extra intermediate buffer and needs more code which adds to code size. The MbedTLS crypto library is direct on this so no extra buffer or code is needed.